# How do I run Cisco AnyConnect VPN on Kubuntu 20.04 using Microsoft Exchange login?

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, cisco

My workplace uses Cisco AnyConnect VPN to connect to our internal network.  The VPN requires us to login to our account using Microsoft login.  Months ago (few months before quarantine), we can use our ID #, and that worked fine, but now we need to login via our Exchange email.

When I try to connect, a window pops up asking me to login to my Exchange account.  After 2FA, normally it would've let me connect (on Windows it works fine), but I'm just stuck and I get the message at the bottom that pops up when the Exchange login window pops up: "Please complete the authentication process in the AnyConnect login..."

I never tried OpenConnect before until now, and I think it would've worked if we were still using our ID to login.  After reading some guides and forums and trying OpenConnect, it won't login, and won't even let me authenticate.

And don't suggest app passwords because they don't even let us use one and we can't use Thunderbird unless we use a plugin that sets it up.